# Why is one View updating and one not, as a variable changes?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this short Code for my swiftUI project:

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var timer: Timer?
    @State var timeGone = 0
    
    func startTimer(){
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: {_ in
            
            timeGone += 1
            
        })
        
    }
    
    var MenuBar: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(String(timeGone))
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.vertical, 1)
                .padding(.horizontal, 4)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1.2)
                ).onAppear {

                }
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 2)
        .padding(.horizontal, 2)
        .background(Color.clear)
        .id("MenuBar")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack{
                Text(String(timeGone))
                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.semibold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .font(.system(size: 90))
                    
            }
            
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 30)
            HStack{
                Button("Start") {
                    startTimer()
                }
                .buttonStyle(StartButtonStyle())
            }
        }
        .fixedSize()
        .frame(width: 340.0, height: 200.0)
        .padding(.all, 50.0)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
import SwiftUI
import Cocoa


class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    

    var statusItem: NSStatusItem!
    
    
    private lazy var contentView: NSView? = {
        let view = (statusItem.value(forKey: "window") as? NSWindow)?.contentView
        return view
    }()
    


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        setupMenuBar()
        
    }
    
 
    func setupMenuBar(){
        
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: 45)
    
        guard let contentView = self.contentView,
              let menuButton = statusItem.button
        else {return}
        
        let hostingView = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView().MenuBar)
        hostingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(hostingView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hostingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            hostingView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor),
            hostingView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor),
            hostingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

}
```

As you can see in the ContentView file, I have the Body view, which is a window with a button on it and a text label containing a variable, which increments every second after the button is pressed. I also have the MenuBar view, which is just a text label with the same variable in it as the previous one. This MenuBar view displays the textLabel on the Menu Bar of MacOS rather than on a window.

What I can't understand is why the second text label updates as the variable changes  but the first one doesn't.

I've not really tried much in particular as I'm not even sure how to approach this. It'd just make sense in my head that both labels update accordingly.

Thanks in advance for any Answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an instance of your `ContentView` that is created for the window.  It has storage for a `timer` and `timerGone` variable.

When you create your menu bar view with:

`let hostingView = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView().MenuBar)`

you are creating a completely new content view (through `ContentView()`) that has its very own storage for a different `timer` and a different `timerGone`.  Those variables have no relationship to the ones created for the window(apart from the fact that the were both built from the same template).

Or to put it another way, you have two complete `ContentView` instances and their types are the only thing they share in common.

To fix the problem you would need to pull the model (in this case the `timerGone` variable) into a separate object that is shared by the two views that display the value.

Here is a playground with an example:

```
import SwiftUI
import Cocoa
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport


// Model class that holds the current tick count
class TimerModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tickCount: Int = 0

    init() {
    }
}

struct TickCountView : View {
    @ObservedObject var timerModel: TimerModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(String(timerModel.tickCount))
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.vertical, 1)
                .padding(.horizontal, 4)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1.2)
                )
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 2)
        .padding(.horizontal, 2)
        .background(Color.clear)
    }
}

struct TimerControlView : View {
    @ObservedObject var timerModel: TimerModel
    @State var timer = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 1.0, runLoop: RunLoop.main, mode: .common)
    @State var cancelTimer: Cancellable?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack{
                Text(String(describing: timerModel.tickCount))
                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.semibold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .font(.system(size: 90))

            }

            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 30)
            HStack{
                Button("Start") {
                    cancelTimer = timer.connect()
                }
            }
        }
        .fixedSize()
        .frame(width: 340.0, height: 200.0)
        .padding(.all, 50.0)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            timerModel.tickCount += 1
        }
    }
}

struct DemonstrationView: View {
    @StateObject var timerModel = TimerModel()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TickCountView(timerModel:  timerModel)
            TimerControlView(timerModel: timerModel)
        }
        .frame(width: 640.0, height: 480.0)
    }
}

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = NSHostingController(rootView: DemonstrationView())
```

In the code the "model", the bit of information that is shared by different views, is stored in an instance of the `TimerModel` class.  This class is an `ObservableObject` so whenever the tick changes, it can notify listeners.

`TickCountView` is a view that can display the `tickCount` in a `TimerModel`.  It gets its value from the `TimerModel` instance you pass it when it's created.

`TimerControlView` is a view that refers to a `TimerModel` instance  and allows you to control it.  It makes use of `TickCountView` and points it at its timerModel, and also adds a button that lets you start the timer.  When the timer fires, it tells the model object to update the tick count.

The `DemonstrationView` creates a single TimerModel instance that will be shared by its multiple subviews.  This instance is the "single source of truth" for the current tick count.  The `DemonstrationView` creates two views that both refer back to this single source of truth.  That way, when you push the button, and the control view starts making changes to the `TimerModel` instance, both views are told about the change and can update what they display.

The important point, for SwiftUI, is that you have a single place where shared information is kept - the single source of truth, and any view that wants to know about that information *references* that truth.  SwiftUI provides tools like `Bindings` or `ObservableObjects` (or `@Observable` in the newest SDKs) to help you set up those references.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for the answer! I do understand what your point is and it does make sense. However, I'm not too sure how to approach fixing it. I've tried creating a class "Singleton" with a variable "a" in it and 2 functions: one which increments "a" and one which returns "a". I don't think this is what you meant by pulling the model into a separate object as it doesn't seem to work. Could you perhaps provide me with further indications please?

Comment: @EdiBociu Look at the example above and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for the example provided and for your time! I've tried following your example and it kind of works. However I can't figure out how to place the TickCountView onto the Menu Bar, as it only shows up onto the main window (https://imgur.com/a/QJY7n9h). I'm sure it's got something to do with this line of code "let hostingView = NSHostingView(rootView: TickCountView(timerModel: TimerModel()))"

Comment: `"let hostingView = NSHostingView(rootView: TickCountView(timerModel: TimerModel()))`. Is the same problem you were having before.  When you call `TimerModel()` you are creating a brand new model, a brand new source of truth, instead creating only one and sharing it with both of your views.  Are you by chance new to Object Oriented Programming?  If so try googling information about the difference between a "class" and an "object", or a "class" and an "instance".

Comment: Yes I actually am new to OOP :) Thanks again, I will look further into it